# Hyperlinks not centering with H1

Tags: html, css

I'm currently trying to make a personal portfolio site for myself using Html, CSS, and JavaScript, and I'm currently just adding some basic CSS for me to work with while I get more page's Html developed and stuff.  Can someone please tell me how I can get the H1 "Logo" to stay left aligned but have the hyperlinks stay centered on the page within the same line?  Thanks!  Here's my code:

Index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
<title>Dean Mysliwiec - Home</title>
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="keywords" content="">
<link href="stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Barlow+Condensed:100,200,300,300i,400" rel="stylesheet">

</head>
<body>
    <p>
        <h1 style="display: inline;">Dean Mysliwiec</h1>
        <a href="index.html" class="main">Home Page</a>
        <a href="photos.html" class="main">Photography</a>
        <a href="websites.html" class="main">Website Work</a>
        <a href="music.html" class="main">Music</a>
        <a href="contact.html" class="main">Contact Me</a>
    </p>

    <h2>Welcome To My Personal Portfolio Website!</h2>
    <h3>Here you will find all of my public work!</h3>
</body>
</html>
```

Stylesheet.css:

```
body {
    background: #4a0a14;

 }

h1 {
    text-align: left;
    color: #4ba8bd;
    font-family: 'Barlow Condensed';
    font-weight: 400;
    font-style: italic;
    font-size: 50px;
    border: 4px solid #18687a;
    width: 253px;
    padding: 5px 3px 5px 3px;
    background: #281f2e;
    border-radius: 3px;

}

h2 {
    text-align: center;
    color: #5fa7b8;
    font-family: 'Barlow Condensed';
    font-weight: 300;
    font-size: 40px;
}
.main {
    font-family: 'Barlow Condensed';
    font-weight: 200;
    font-size: 30px;
    color: #7cd2e6;
    border: 1px solid #72a3ad;
    background: #26202b;
    padding: 5px 13px 5px 13px;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-radius: 20px;
    text-shadow: 3px 3px 8px #4c464f;
    text-align: center; 
}
h3 {
    font-family: 'Barlow Condensed';
    font-weight: 100;
    font-size: 30px;
    color: #5fc7a4;
    text-align: center;

}
```

Comment: Side note, paragraph elements can't contain headings

Comment: I would seriously consider doing a few HTML and CSS courses before you go ahead and make yourself a portfolio site, you can't nest `h1` or `a` in p tags...

Answer (score -1):

Why you insert `h1` and `a` inside `p`? You know about `div`? `nav`? `ul > li`?
Why you use `.css` file + inline style in HTML?

Read about HTML structure, imho.

And learn flexbox, it's answer to your question.

Answer (score -1):

```html
</head>
<body>
    <p>
        <h1 style="display: inline;">Dean Mysliwiec</h1>
      &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp
      &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp
      &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp
      &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp
  <a href="index.html" class="main">Home Page</a>
        <a href="photos.html" class="main">Photography</a>
----- and so on.
```

This will lead to your answer adding &nbsp

Comment: You can not be serious.